# Does deleting copied pointers to differing pointer types cause a memory leak?

Tags: c++, memory, pointers, memory-leaks

I've narrowed down in my application that my AVI video player is leaking memory. I have the following code:

```
...

LPBYTE pChunk = new BYTE[lSize];
if(!pChunk)
    return false;

hr = AVIStreamReadFormat(pStream, AVIStreamStart(pStream), pChunk, &lSize);
if(hr)
{
    delete [] pChunk;
    return false;
}

m_pVideoFormats[i] = (LPBITMAPINFO)pChunk;
```

Later on when it comes time to remove the video, I simply just delete:

```
if(m_pVideoFormats[i])
    delete [] ((LPBYTE)m_pVideoFormats[i]);
```

Will this cause a memory leak because of how I'm casting this pointer around? Thanks!

Comment: No, the object knows its own size when it gets deleted, regardless of any casting. As a sidenote, checking for being different from NULL is not needed, as delete of a NULL pointer is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that won't leak. It doesn't matter how you cast it around, the important thing is that you delete the same type you allocated. You've matched `BYTE[]` to `BYTE[]`, so that's not your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't leak memory, but you're doing some unnecessary things.

1. Checking for `nullptr` after `new` is pointless since `std::bad_alloc` is thrown instead of a `nullptr` being returned if allocation fails.
2. Similarly, checking for `nullptr` before `delete` is unnecessary since `delete [] nullptr` is perfectly valid.

Also, use smart pointers instead of managing pointers to raw chunks of memory.

```
std::unique_ptr<BYTE[]> pChunk;

try {
  pChunk.reset( new BYTE[lSize] );
} catch( const std::bad_alloc& ) {
  return false;
}

hr = AVIStreamReadFormat(pStream, AVIStreamStart(pStream), pChunk, &lSize);
if(hr)
{
    // delete [] pChunk; // not needed - smart pointer will free memory
    return false;
}

m_pVideoFormats[i] = (LPBITMAPINFO)pChunk.release();

...

delete [] ((LPBYTE)m_pVideoFormats[i]);
m_pVideoFormats[i] = nullptr; // set to nullptr to avoid double deletion
```

Comment: Thanks, however I've overloaded new operator so it would return NULL in failure cases. That's why it's there. Your second point is valid though.